# Cannot find namespace 'firebase'

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2:

> ```
> Your system information:
>
>  ordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: Windows 10
> Node Version: v6.9.2
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

When I run `ionic serve`, I get the following error:

> ```
> Typescript Error
> Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
> ...t/IDE/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo-chat/node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.d.ts
> constructor(fbConfig: FirebaseAppConfig);
> list(urlOrRef: string | firebase.database.Reference, opts?: FirebaseListFactoryOpts): FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
> object(urlOrRef: string | firebase.database.Reference, opts?: FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts): FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
> ```

This is a new Ionic project created with `ionic start ...`.

If anyone can suggest how I can resolve this, I would appreciate it.

I think it may be related to compatibles withing Ionic versions. The reason I say this, is because I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvzuhkEtGPg&index=1&list=PLMEbEXZJWgoR4GAnwXq2mwk9G6ssheukP) tutorial, and I guess he isn't using `Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4`. His example has an `app.ts`, where I split it into `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts` as required by rc.4.

More info:

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "firebase3": "file:node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.3-0930330",
    "firebase": "^3.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.47",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "theWhoZoo-chat: An Ionic project"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase, AngularFire, FirebaseAuth } from 'angularfire2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase({
      apiKey: "xxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com"
    })]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have resolved my issue.

Adding the following to `app.component.ts`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
...
    firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "baseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
    });
```